# Enabling Twitter card on specific sub domain

Tags: twitter, twitter-card

Say  **example.com** has two sub domains **X1.example.com** and **X2.example.com**.

How to enable twitter card only on X1 ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking questions, please provide a specific example of what you're trying to achieve and also what you've currently done. In its current state, your question can't really be answered and may be closed. To learn more about asking great questions, see How to Ask- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. You can also take a look at the About page and if you ever need to check over something, the Help center- http://stackoverflow.com/help is a good resource. Thank you!